# standard library function substitution replace_if_match

Tags: c++, std-function

I have created a hangman game.  I would like to know if there is a robust way to implement this function and if not is there a standard library function I could use instead?  I am using the function to replace the blanks in guessed_word only if their guess matches a part of the random_word.

**function implementation**

```
std::pair<std::string&, std::size_t> replace_if_match(
    std::string&       write, 
    const std::string& read, 
    const std::string& match
    )
{

    assert( write.length() >= read.length() );

    int occurrences{0};

    for(
        int search_pos{0};
        (search_pos = read.find( match, search_pos )) != -1; 
        ++search_pos, ++occurrences){

        write.replace( search_pos, match.length(), match );
    }

    return {write, occurrences};
}
```

**use of function**

```
// I have not yet implemented the random word 
std::string random_word{"timeless"};

// set number of guesses
int guesses{5};

// set guessed word to length of random word in underscores 
std::string guessed_word{
    std::string().append(random_word.length(),'_')
};

// enter guessing loop as long as
// guesses is greater than or equal to zero
while( guesses > 0 && random_word != guessed_word )
{
    // display guessed word in progress
    std::cout << guessed_word << '\n'; 

    // display number of guesses left 
    std::cout << "Number of Guesses Left: " << guesses << '\n';

    // prompt user to enter a guess
    std::cout << "Enter a string as guess." << '\n';
    static std::string guess;
    std::cin >> guess;

    // the guessed word will be modified in the if statement via function; therefore, the value must be stored to look back on 
    static std::string prev_word; 
    prev_word = guessed_word;

    // guess fails to succeed if the guessed word does not change
    if( prev_word == replace_if_match( guessed_word, random_word, guess ).first )
    {
        guesses--;
    }
} 
if( guessed_word == random_word )
{
    std::cout << "You winza!!!! ";
}
else
{ 
    std::cout << "Game over yeah!!!! "; 
}
```

Comment: just to be sure, what do you want the result to be if the player enters "lesstime" ? Is that a match or not?

Comment: No, "lesstime" is not a match, but "less" and then "time" are matches